# Hive - LIKE Operator

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sql-like

I can not figure out how I deal with that problem:

This is my Data:

```
Table1:         Table2:
BRAND           PRODUCT           SOLD
Sony            Sony ABCD         1233
Apple           Sony adv          1233
Google          Sony aaaa         1233
IBM             Apple 123         1233
etc.            Apple 345         1233
                IBM 13123         1233
```

Is it possible to filter the query that I have a table where stands the brand and the total solds?
My idea is:

```
Select table1.brand, sum(table2.sold) from table1
join table2
on (table1.brand LIKE '%table2.product%')
group by table.1.brand
```

That was my idea, but i always get an Error

The biggest problem is the Like-Operator or is there any other solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628396/hive-like-operator Please Check and advise for above similar Quear.
Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see two issues: First of all, JOINs in hive only work with equality conditions, that like isn't going to work there.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

> Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in Hive. Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce job.

Instead, that wants to go into a where clause.

Secondly, I also see a problem with the like statement itself: '%table2.product%' is being interpreted as literally the string '%table2.product%'.  Additionally, even if this was doing what was intended, it would try to look for table2.product inside of brand, when you seem to want it the other way.  To get the evaluation you intended, you need to add the wildcard to the contents of table1.brand; to accomplish this, you want to concatenate your wildcards into your expression.

```
table2.product LIKE concat('%',table1.brand,'%'))
```

By doing this, your like will evaluate for strings '%Sony%', '%Apple%'...etc instead of '%table2.product%'.

What you want is Brandon Bell's query, which I've merged into this answer:

```
SELECT table1.brand, SUM(table2.sold) 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.product LIKE concat('%', table1.brand, '%') 
GROUP BY table1.brand;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to accomplish this without a JOIN.  See the following query:

```
SELECT table1.brand, sum(table2.sold) 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table2.product LIKE concat('%', table1.brand, '%') 
GROUP BY table1.brand;
```

This returns

```
Apple   2466
IBM     1233
Sony    3699
```

Where my input files are as follows:

```
Sony
Apple
Google
IBM
```

and

```
Sony ABCD       1233
Sony adv        1233
Sony aaaa       1233
Apple 123       1233
Apple 345       1233
IBM 13123       1233
```

Comment: Just to clarify that an implicit join is a join.  Performance wise they should be the same.  "FROM a,b WHERE a.ID = b.ID" is syntactic sugar for "FROM a JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID". :)