# hive join with like operator

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I have two tables which are using ORC compression and am using TEZ as execution engine. Table_a contains more than 900k records and table_b contains 17 million records. This query taking longer time I have waited for 2 days but the query execution was not completed. what am I doing wrong in this query.

```
select min(up.id) as comp002uniqueid, min(cp.product_id) as p_id 
from 
(select * from table_a where u_id is null) up ,  table_b cp 
where  cp.title like concat('% ',up.productname,' %') 
group by up.productname;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  `Lac` and `Crore` are figures used only in India - it will be helpful if you used thousands, millions or billions for number of records so that larger audience can related with your question.

Comment: Also some logs would be useful. Do you have the same problem with the Map Reduce execution engine?

Comment: a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340218/hive-like-operator

Comment: yes i have tried that solution but it did not work for me..